# rerender chart in vue-chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

How should I refer to the chart in a vue chart instance and destroy it? I've tried:

```
var chartVue = new Vue({
  el: '#chart',
  extends: VueChartJs.Line,
  data: {
    chartData: {...},
    options: {...}
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderMyChart()
  },
  methods: { 
    renderMyChart: function() {
      this.renderChart(
        this.chartData,
        this.options
        );
    }
  },
  watch: {
    chartData: function() {
      this._chart.destroy();
      this.renderMyChart();
    }
  }
});
```

But it complains

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

So it seems `this._chart` is not the right way to refer to the current chart, anybody knows what is the right way to do this? The idea comes from [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728332/vue-chart-js-chart-is-not-updating-when-data-is-changing).

Comment: `this._chart` is the correct reference, so I'm not sure why it would be `undefined` at that point. But also, you can just use the `reactiveData` mixin, which does exactly what you're trying to do: http://vue-chartjs.org/#/home?id=reactive-data

Comment: Hi @thanksd, thanks for the reply. I've looked into `mixin`s but not sure how to use it directly in a vue instance. The example shows how to use it in a vue component. Do you how how I can use reactiveProp here?

Comment: Just add `mixins: [ VueChartJs.mixins.reactiveData ],`. And note that it does need to be `reactiveData` and not `reactiveProp` since you've defined `chartData` in your data object and not as a passed in prop. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fuj4yqke/

Comment: @thanksd Excellent. I think that's the trick I am missing. I was trying `reactiveProp` all the time. It's working perfectly now. If you don't mind post as an answer, I'll upvote and accept it. The documentation does not seem very clear about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Chart` object accessible via `this._chart` is not set until after the `renderChart` method is called. What's most likely happening is that your `chartData` is somehow being updated before that `renderChart` method has been called. So, the watcher for `chartData` is referencing `this._chart` before it has been defined.

However, `vue-chartjs` has a baked-in way to re-render the chart when the dependant data change: the [`reactiveData` and `reactiveProp` mixins](http://vue-chartjs.org/#/home?id=reactive-data). By adding either of these mixins, the changes to the `chartData` (data-property or prop, respectively) will re-render the chart to reflect the updated data.

You should use the `reactiveData` mixin instead:

```
var chartVue = new Vue({
  el: '#chart',
  extends: VueChartJs.Line,
  mixins: [ VueChartJS.mixins.reactiveData ],
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {...}, 
      options: {...}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems `this._chart` has been moved to `this._data._chart`, so for instance to make the options reactive, add a watcher as follows:

```
watch: {
    options: function() {
        this._data._chart.destroy();
        this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
    }
}
```